# AMPL: can I define alternate names for members of an index set?

Tags: ampl

I'm using AMPL for work involving a large table that is indexed by "Industries" (a set of 67 different industries) and "Products" (a set of 301 different products).

Each of these industries and products has two different "names" that could be used. One is a numeric code; the other is a plain-English descriptor. For example, "Paper and paperboard" is the same thing as product # 15010.

I would like to be able to use both these name methods interchangeably, so that AMPL understands that "15010" is just an alternate name for "Paper and paperboard".

Is there a feature that does this? I can think of a hack based on using a set of numeric codes that's indexed by the plain-English names and vice versa, but I'm looking for something a bit less hack-y.